# Center react native view

Tags: css, react-native

I'm creating a component to show the flag and country name. I'll like that view (image + text) centered in the available space.
So if the width of parent is all the screen, there will be space in the left and same in the right. If the parent is only 50% of the screen will be then left space on the sides...

What I've done:

```
      <View style={styles.mainContainer} >
          <View >
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={this.props.disablePicker}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: true, dataSource: this.props.dataSource })}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            >
              <View>
          <View style={[pickerStyle,{ flexDirection:'row'}]} >
            <Image style={{}} source={selectedLabel.image} />
            <Text style={}>{selectedLabel.name}</Text>
            {dropDownImage ? <Image
              style={dropDownImageStyle}
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={dropDownImage}
            /> : null}
          </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    </View>


const CountryPickerStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  itemSeparatorStyle:{
    height: 1,
    width: "90%",
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3"
  },
  searchBarContainerStyle: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 40,
    shadowOpacity: 1.0,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 1
    },
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    shadowColor: "#d3d3d3",
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 3,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },

  selectLabelTextStyle: {
    color: "#000",
    fontSize:16,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginLeft: 100,
    marginRight: 100
  },
  placeHolderTextStyle: {
    color: "#757575",
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: "left",
    width: "99%",
    fontStyle: 'italic', 
    fontSize:12,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  dropDownImageStyle: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: "#757575",
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  listTextViewStyle: {
    color: "#000",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  pickerStyle: {
    elevation:0,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    width:"90%",
    borderWidth:0   ,
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});
```

here's what I got:
https://pasteboard.co/JG5Rx9P.png
and also https://pasteboard.co/JG5Tthie.png

Comment: If I understand correctly, give the second view a display flex as a row or column (depending on what you want to achieve) and justify content and aligns-items centre

Comment: that's what I have... but not working correctly

Comment: you have to share the rest of the code if you say you have it. There is no evidence in the post to the existence of it

Comment: added all the stylesheet

Comment: notice your pickerStyle, missing display:flex?

Comment: what should I put? I'm not good at styling

Comment: in your pickerStyle add display: flex / justify-content: center / align-items: center

Comment: let me know if that works and I will post an answer with a bit more detail

Comment: got that:  https://pasteboard.co/JG62nOb.png

Comment: on the 100% space got: https://pasteboard.co/JG63rAH.png

Comment: it's difficult to read your code in that layout to be honest but it seems you are struggling to understand the basics of using flex box. Notice the amount of times you use "flex-direction" without setting the display to be flex. That is wrong. The "rule will be ignored. read this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and if you want more help include your code in a sandbox or snippet

Comment: Ok. how do I do a snippet? My main problem is setting the view width....

Comment: use code sandbox and post it here